# Nesting / hierarchical modeling in a pre-post study

Tags: multilevel-analysis, nested-data

We are conducting a study which has a pre-post design.  The unit of the study is the outpatient visit. In each visit, we study how patients and physicians interact.

Each physician will see between 3-6 patients and most of these patients (ie, except for dropouts) will be seen twice: once in the pre-phase, once in the post-phase.

Because the relation of patient to physician in any given visit is symmetric, it would seem to lead to two distinct ways to model the hierarchical structure. Starting from the root vertex of the (directed) tree:

A) study $\to$ physician $\to$ patient $\to$ pre/post

B) study $\to$ pre/post $\to$ physician $\to$ patient

Is there a scientific reason or stat. methodological issues to prefer one nesting over the other? What differences in results can we expect?

Any pointers to the literature are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a good reason to prefer (A) over (B).

(A) correctly reflects the design of the study, while (B) does not. The two models are not equivalent, and the choice is not arbitrary.

Model (B) posits that Physicians are nested under Pre/post, as are Patients (by virtue of being nested under Physicians), but clearly neither of these is true. To say that Physicians are nested under Pre/post would be to say that each Physician is observed under one and only one level of Pre/post... that is, we have some Physicians that are "Pre Physicians", and other Physicians that are "Post Physicians", but no Physician has both Pre *and* Post observations (according to model B).

But in actual fact, each Physician *does* have some Pre observations and some Post observations. And because the Pre/post observations under one Physician are different from the Pre/post observations under another Physician, we can see that the order of nesting is actually the reverse... Pre/post is nested under Physician, not vice versa. And of course, Patients are in the middle of this hierarchy.

The difference here is not merely conceptual. There are tangible statistical consequences that follow from the choice of (A) or (B). Perhaps most saliently in this case, in model (A) the denominator of the test for the Pre vs. Post difference is free of variance due to both Physician and Patient, because these are held constant when comparing Pre-scores to Post-scores. (This becomes slightly more complicated in the presence of unbalanced/missing data, but we'll ignore that for now.) In model (B), Physician and Patient variance are both (wrongly) thrown in the denominator for testing the Pre vs. Post difference. This is "wrong" in the sense that it leads to a test of the Pre vs. Post difference that is overly conservative.

Comment: Jake, +1 for the explanation. Before I accept, however, can you explain what you mean in the last paragraph by "post difference is free of variance"? Two issues: (1) we are not necessarily hypothesis testing, but primarily estimating correlation structure. (2) We observe variation in captured data across visits even with the same physician and patient, because it is a distinct visit with distinct issues and workflow. What is "held constant"?

Comment: I don't think you parsed that sentenced the way I intended. Putting it differently: the *t*-ratio for testing the difference between Pre-scores and Post-scores does not contain Physician variance (i.e., variance due to Physician means) or Patient variance (i.e., variance due to Patient means). This is what I mean when I say that Physicians and Patients are "held constant" (not allowed to vary) when testing the Pre vs. Post difference. The *t* denominator does, of course, still contain other sources of variance, but overall the denominator of this *t* is smaller in (A) than it is in (B).

Comment: What scores do you mean? We are studying detailed interaction at the level of process data, eg second-by-second time-motion study combining video cameras and computer interface data capture. Every summary measure we have looked at so far varies greatly from visit to visit, eg length of visit, ratio of physicians' gaze to computer vs. gaze to patient, amount of computer activity, vocalization and verbal communication patterns. I'm not sure what pre-scores and post-scores refer to. Do you mean, regardless of the measure, the averages (across physicians) are constant in each phase?

Comment: A "score" refers to an individual value of whatever outcome measure you are looking at in each visit, i.e., the dependent variable. So maybe for one model it is the gaze ratio you mentioned, or maybe a value representing amount of computer activity, or whatever. A "pre-score" is a value of this outcome variable during the "pre" phase, and likewise a "post-score" is a value in the "post" phase. Sorry if this confused you, it is pretty standard terminology in my field. What I mean about holding things constant is this:

Comment: If I want to know how scores change when moving from the "pre" phase to the "post" phase I can, conceptually speaking, compare each patient's pre-score to *that same patient's* post-score. Because this comparison is not influenced by the mean for that Patient or for that Physician (i.e., it doesn't matter if the patient is an overall "high responder" or "low responder"; you can add an arbitrary constant to both the pre-score and post-score and still get the same answer regarding change), we can therefore say that the comparison of pre to post is free of Patient variance and Physician variance.

Comment: This is *NOT* to say that the scores don't vary at all! Obviously they do, as you noted. There is probably still a lot of *error variance* left over even after accounting for Patient variance and Physician variance. Anyway, I think I have now answered your original question more than sufficiently. Just go with model (A).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to go for something along option A). Obviously, patients are nested within physicians, i.e. you want to account for the effect of physicians on your measurements. Finally, you are dealing with repeated measures on the patient level.

Approaching the multilevel/hierarchical modeling this way guarantees the correct shrinkage towards the appropriate levels of hierarchy. You want the individual time courses to tend towards the 'average' time course for this particular physician, which in turn shrinks toward the sample 'average'.

Comment: Thanks. However, patients are nested within physicians in both A. and B. So that doesn't seem to resolve it.

Comment: Well B) is sort of implying that there is a 'pre- and post-physician' in addition to the 'pre- and post-patient'. In other words, option A) implies that there is something unique about a particular physician, while option B) implies that there is something unique about the time point (pre/post) at which all physicians sees their patients.